# PhantomJS get array of positions for specific element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to get positions of a specific tag on a page using phantomjs. for example for `<a>` tags I want to get this array :

```
[
   {
       tag: "a",
       x: 12,
       y: 32,
       width: 100,
       height: 30
   },
   ...
]
```

I wrote this code:

```
page.open(url, function(status){
   ....
   ....
   var a_tags = page.evaluate(function() {
                     return document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                });

   for(index in a_tags){
      console.log(a_tags[index].getBoundingClientRect());
   }
   ....
   ....
})
```

But this code returns an error :

```
TypeError: null is not a function (evaluating 'a_tags[index].getBoundingClientRect()')
```

How can I get this information from a page using phantomjs and what is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
var a_tags = page.evaluate(function() {
      var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      var res = [];
      for(var index = 0 ; index < tags.length ; index++) {
          var element = tags[index];
          var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          if(rect.left == 0 && rect.top ==0 || rect.width ==0 && rect.height ==0){
                     continue;
          }
          res.push({
                tag: "a",
                rect: rect,
          });
      }
      return res;
});
```